# How do I make unbound controls writeable?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access 2013 database that I am porting all tables and queries to SQL Server.  After unbinding the controls on a form, I am unable to make them editable.

The form I am working with has a combo box, and a text box that are loaded from ADODB recordsets populated with data returned from Stored procedures.
I have tried to make the controls (Combo box, and text box) editable by changing the "Locked" and "Enabled" properties, and I have set the form's AllowEdits to True, but I am unable to change the selected text in the combo box or change text in the text box.

```vb
Private Sub cboCombo_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Me.cboCombo.Locked = False
    Me.cboCombo.Enabled = True
    Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyTab, vbKeyPageUp, vbKeyPageDown, vbKeyEnd, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyHome, vbKeyExecute, vbKeyEscape
    Case Else
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
    End Select
End Sub
```

I want to be able to make a selection, but when the program is running, the status text repeatedly says the form is read only.

Comment: It sounds like the source query of the form is read-only.

Comment: `Me.cboCombo.Enabled = True` -- if your combo box is disabled before, it won't even receive the KeyDown. I think.

Comment: I have made some progress.  What can be done is break the recordset's active connection before assigning it to the form.  What is particularly frustrating is knowing that Microsoft can make what I am doing so much easier, instead they'd rather drive the coder's crazy.

Comment: Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
   cnn.Open gconConnectOLEDB
      
   Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
   With rst
     Set .ActiveConnection = cnn
         .Source = "EXEC spGetCompanyInfo " & lngCompanyID
         .LockType = adLockOptimistic
         .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
  .CursorLocation = adUseClient
         .Open
   End With
   Set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
   Set Me.Recordset = rst

   Me.txtName.ControlSource = "Name"
   Me.txtAddress.ControlSource = "Address"